# error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8

Tags: encoding, utf-8

error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8.  Because of copyright character, I am getting this error. I am using Netbeans 7.2.

```
/**
 *  � 2006
 * 
 * This class was generated by the JAX-WS RI.
 * JAX-WS RI 2.2.6-2b01 
 * Generated source version: 2.1
 *
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you have two options:

- Call the generator using a command-line parameter to generate UTF-8 instead of whatever it's using by default. (You haven't said where this file actually comes from, but I assume the generation is under your control somewhere...)
- Change how Netbeans handles the file, telling it what encoding it's really in

Personally I'd favour the first option if possible - UTF-8 is a nice "everything supports it" encoding

Answer (score 8):

You have to set the project's encoding correctly.

Right click on your project -> Properties -> Sources -> Encoding

Windows 1252 is a good option to try. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the project node in the Projects window and choose Properties.
In the left column under Categories, select Sources.
And set it to ISO-8859-1

Answer (score 0):

*I used all of the solutions here, but the problem persisted*.
Finally,

*I have resolved this problem:*

- by changing the netbeans version(**From 'version 8.2' to 'apache version 11'**)